# Bootstrap modal doesn't get user ID

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, modal-dialog

I have a problem with a bootstrap modal. I'm using PHP.

In an admin panel there is a table with the list of the users and the possibility to edit or delete a user's profile. For the delete I want to create a modal for the confirm of the delete but, when I click on "confirm" button inside the modal, the modal gets by default the user ID of the first user in the table and not the user ID of the selected user.

Here is the code:

```html
<?php foreach ($utenti as $utente) { ?>
<tr>

  <th scope="row"> <?php echo $utente['idUser']?> </th>

  <td><?php echo $utente['nome']." ".$utente['cognome']?></td>
  <?php if($_SESSION['role'] == 1) {?>
  <td><?php echo $utente['az']?></td>
  <?php } ?>

  <td><?php echo $utente['email']?></td>

  <td class="text-warning"><a
    href="<?php echo 'editUser.php?user='.$utente['idUser']?>"><i
    class="fas fa-edit text-warning"></i></a></td>
  <!--    <td class="text-warning"><a href="  "><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i></a></td> -->
  <td class="text-danger">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#confirmDelete"><i
      class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i><?php var_dump($utente['idUser']); ?>
    </button>
  </td>

  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="confirmDelete">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">
            Attenzione <?php var_dump($utente['idUser']); ?></h5>

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Continuando eliminerai l'utente in maniera irreversibile</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger "
          ><a
            class="text-white btn-modal-confirm"
            href="<?php echo '?action=delete&user='.$utente['idUser']?>"
          >Elimina</a>
          </button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Indietro
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</tr>

<?php }?>
```

If I make a var_dump of `$utente['idUser']` before the modal, it gets the right user ID. If I make it inside the modal it gets by default the first ID, as I said.

Comment: If this is in a loop, here's your problem: `id="confirmDelete"` - every modal has the same id. Meaning it will always fetch the first one, as ids need to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that every modal trigger button has a `data-target` attribute to define which modal will be opened.

In your case, the button of every row you used to triggered the modal have the same `data-target`, which is `#confirmDelete`. These modals behind also has the same `id` called `#confirmDelete`, so every time you hit the modal trigger button (all had the same `data-target`) then eventually it will shows up the very first modal element.

For a better understanding, compare my code to yours and see the differences.

```
<?php foreach ($utenti as $utente) { ?>
<tr>

  <th scope="row"> <?php echo $utente['idUser']?> </th>

  <td><?php echo $utente['nome']." ".$utente['cognome']?></td>
  <?php if($_SESSION['role'] == 1) {?>
  <td><?php echo $utente['az']?></td>
  <?php } ?>

  <td><?php echo $utente['email']?></td>

  <td class="text-warning"><a
    href="<?php echo 'editUser.php?user='.$utente['idUser']?>"><i
    class="fas fa-edit text-warning"></i></a></td>
  <!--    <td class="text-warning"><a href="  "><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i></a></td> -->
  <td class="text-danger">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#confirmDelete_<?php echo $utente['idUser']; ?>"><i
      class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i><?php var_dump($utente['idUser']); ?>
    </button>
  </td>

  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="confirmDelete_<?php echo $utente['idUser']; ?>">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">
            Attenzione <?php echo $utente['idUser']; ?></h5>

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Continuando eliminerai l'utente in maniera irreversibile</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger "
          ><a
            class="text-white btn-modal-confirm"
            href="<?php echo '?action=delete&user='.$utente['idUser']?>"
          >Elimina</a>
          </button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Indietro
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</tr>

<?php }?>
```

In the above code, I gave every pair of modal elements (modal trigger button and modal ID) a unique `data-target` value and a unique element id.

```
...
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#confirmDelete_<?php echo $utente['idUser']; ?>">
...
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="confirmDelete_<?php echo $utente['idUser']; ?>">
...
```

Now each pair of modal elements have their own `ids` and they should be working the way you wanted.

Comment: @ValerioMassari If my answer solved your problem then just mark it as "Best answer".